# i got an error in my script while i switch platform to android in unity . BCE0019: 'position' is not a member of 'Object'

Tags: javascript, unityscript

```
var steerVector : Vector3 = 
     transform.InverseTransformPoint(Vector3(path[currentPathObj].position.x , 
     transform.position.y , path[currentPathObj].position.z)) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `waypoints` variable. Maybe it is just of Array type, Change that to `Transform[]`. 
Example

```
var waypoints : Transform[];
waypoints = waypointContainer.GetComponentsInChildren.<Transform>();
```